# How can i make a fixed size for button

Tags: android, android-layout, button

When i make a button in XML... it's size change from one device to another it's seem small in one device and very big on another and 
how can i make a constant size at every device that "APK" Setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Define the exact width and height for the button on your layout xml,

```
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

For do this you can use dp, dpi unit in layout_whidth and layout_height parameters. Instead wrap_content or fill_parent, this units are designed for do that.

Then you can define with this units to obtain a constant size of your button on all screens.